# SQL Query for repeated row set NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Parent as well as Child table...
Master table : SalesInvoice

```
ID    ToatlQty    Unit
 1         100    BOX
 2         110    BOX
```

Detail Table : SalesInvoiceDetail

```
DetailsID    ID   ItemMasterID    Qty   Unit
       01     1   000000001010    25    BOX
       02     1   000000001010    25    BOX
       03     1   000000001013    30    BOX
       04     2   000000001014    50    BOX
```

I want output like

```
ID  ItemMasterID    Unit   TotalQty   Qty
 1  000000001010    BOX         100   50
 1  000000001013    BOX           0   30
 2  000000001014    BOX         110   50
```

I have got TotalQty '100' two time for ID '1' but i want set 0 if it is repeated.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: That seems like a relatively straightforward query to do, you'll have to use a JOIN on the IDs of both tables and then a GROUP BY with a SUM on Qty.

Comment: Hint: `SUM`, `group by` and `coalesce`

Comment: Please add your current output

Answer (score 1):

The query below is built with following assumptions: you need TotalQty 0 for repeated values if they have higher ItemMasterID, sum Qty by ID and ItemMasterID (based on the output). Let me know if they are wrong. The query includes sample data and can be run as is:

```
-- sample data
;with SalesInvoice as (
    select * from (values 
        (1, 100, 'BOX'),
        (2, 110, 'BOX')
    ) t(ID, TotalQty, Unit)
),
SalesInvoiceDetail as (
    select * from (values 
        (1, 1, '000000001010', 25, 'BOX'),
        (2, 1, '000000001010', 25, 'BOX'),
        (3, 1, '000000001013', 30, 'BOX'),
        (4, 2, '000000001014', 50, 'BOX')
    ) t (DetailsID, ID, ItemMasterID, Qty, Unit)    
)

-- solution
select 
    t.ID, 
    t.ItemMasterID,
    SalesInvoice.Unit,
    TotalQty = 
        case when ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by t.id order by ItemMasterID) = 1 
        then TotalQty else 0 end,
    t.Qty
from (
    select id, ItemMasterID, Qty = sum(qty) from SalesInvoiceDetail
    group by id, ItemMasterID
) t
join SalesInvoice on t.id = SalesInvoice.ID
```

Comment: No need to use subquery. You can use `join`, `group by` and `row_number()` in one step... +1  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    A.Id ,
        A.ItemMasterID ,
        A.Unit ,
        ISNULL(B.ToatlQty, 0) AS ToatlQty ,
        A.Qty
FROM      ( SELECT    Id ,
                    ItemMasterID ,
                    Unit ,
                    SUM(Qty) AS Qty
          FROM      SalesInvoiceDetail A
          GROUP BY  Id ,
                    ItemMasterID ,
                    Unit
        ) A
        LEFT JOIN SalesInvoice B ON A.ID = B.ID
```